# Поддержка удобств Notepad++ в Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Есть ли альтернатива `Notepad`'овским функциям в `Visual Studio Code`?

- Макросы. Если их нет, какая есть возможная замена?
- Функции, выполняющиеся в `Notepad++` на сочетания клавиш, а именно:

  - `Ctrl + D` - клонирование выделенного участка текста или строки
  - `Ctrl + Shift + Up/Down` - перемещение вверх/вниз выделенного участка текста или строки

Comment: Ctrl-D == Ctrl+Ins, Shift+Ins

Comment: Alt+Shift+Up/Down — создание копии текущей строки над/под ней. Alt-Up/Down — перемещение текущей строки вверх/вниз.

Comment: расширение [ms-vscode.notepadplusplus-keybindings](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.notepadplusplus-keybindings)

Answer (score 0):

Для дублирования выделенного текста или строки при отсутствии выделения можно использовать расширение [Contextual Duplicate](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lafe.contextualduplicate).

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+d",
    "command": "lafe.duplicateCode",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
},
```

перемещение вверх/вниз строки (при выделении все равно перемещается строка с курсором)

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+up",
    "command": "editor.action.moveLinesUpAction",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly",
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+down",
    "command": "editor.action.moveLinesDownAction",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly",
},
```